# Magento 2 Custom Module Cron Job often missed

Tags: magento2, cron, magento-cron

I'm using Magento version 2.2.5 and I've created a cron job for my custom module, but it's often missed, first I setup the cron to run every 5 minutes

```
<group id="default"> 
  <job instance="Custom\Module\Cron\SyncTransaction" method="execute" name="lime_sepulsa_synctransaction">
    <schedule>*/5 * * * *</schedule>
  </job>
</group>
```

[image]

then I tried to fix it by setting up the cron to run every minute, but still got the same result

```
<group id="default"> 
  <job instance="Custom\Module\Cron\SyncTransaction" method="execute" name="lime_sepulsa_synctransaction">
    <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
  </job>
</group>
```

[image]

Comment: First check cron log.

Comment: @DhadukMitesh no error in cron log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your cronjob group id from `default` to `index` if you want your cron to run every minute without being missed:

```
<group id="index"> 
  <job instance="Custom\Module\Cron\SyncTransaction" method="execute" name="lime_sepulsa_synctransaction">
    <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
  </job>
</group>
```

by default cronjob group with id `default` will run every 15 minutes but `index` group will run every minute